# How to design in flutter as image below & How to open & close tabs?

Tags: flutter

```
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text('Group Name-1'),
          ],
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
));
```

I have to design as per image shown in flutter & also how to open & close tabs as per image shown?

**  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrX02.png

Comment: Checkout this package https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) Widget

```
   ExpansionTile(
          title:  //define your header widget here 
     Text(
            "fsfs",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
          ),
  
    
          children: 
    
    <Widget>[
//define your widget here which you want to show on expand
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                items.description,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```